Not getting the updated value in Ag grid cell render when value changes after API call
Hi i am using react query and fetching data below
const { data: projectStatusList } = GetAllProjectQueryStatus();
i am passing this projectStatusList as a prop to component whIch is inside Ag Grid cellRenderer
but the updated value of projectStatusList not reflected in cellRenderer . Also if i console  projectStatusList  outside the cellRendrer
i can see the updated value
I’m using react-query to fetch a list of project statuses and pass it as a prop to a component that is rendered inside an ag-Grid cellRenderer. However, I'm facing an issue where the updated value of projectStatusList is not reflected within the cellRenderer. Interestingly, if I log projectStatusList outside the cellRenderer, I can see the updated values. But inside the cellRenderer, the value remains stale.
Here is the data fetching and how it's passed to the cellRenderer:
const { data: projectStatusList } = GetAllProjectQueryStatus();
This projectStatusList is passed as a prop to the component in the cellRenderer:
cellRenderer: ({ data }) => { return ( <div className={classNames(styles.ColumnLeftPadding, 'mx-auto position-relative')}> <Popper title={data?.status_label} type={fomatTextCapitalize(data?.status)} options={optionsProjects} onSelect={(item) => { if (isRestrictActions(screenEnum.project, screenActionEnum.update)) { changeTableData(data, item?.type, item?.label, item?.color); } }} onAdd={(dataItem) => { addProjectStatusMutate(dataItem); }} onUpdate={(dataItem) => { updateStatusMutate(dataItem); }} onDelete={(dataItem) => { DeStatuslMutate(dataItem); }} isLoadingDel={DelStatusLoading} data={projectStatusList}  // Passing projectStatusList here buttonID={PopperButton_${data?.status_label}${data.index}} color={data?.status_color} /> </div> ); } 
The issue is:
projectStatusList is passed as a prop, but when the value changes, it doesn't update within the cellRenderer.
The projectStatusList logs the correct value outside the cellRenderer, but the change is not reflected inside it.

Please update the above question by, making a small example code which produces exact same behavior/problem. Is this code from Angular or React according to the tags.
